# Apache configuration for installing Redmine in URL subdirectory

Tags: apache, redmine

I have a problem about configuring apache for my installed Redmine.

I've installed Redmine (v 1.2.1) in `/usr/local/lib/` directory successfully and it works. I want to configure apache so that Redmine would be accessible through http://myhost/redmine while I've installed a wordpress-based website in `/var/www` binded to http://myhost/. What should I do?

Here my current apache configuration (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-redmine`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2.1/public
        ServerSignature off

        <Directory />
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2.1/public>
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also follow the FAQ from the Redmine site: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI

Answer (score 0):

I used Phusion Passenger for the Ruby plugin. I then symlinked the public folder to /var/www/redmine.

My Apache config has:

```
RailsBaseURI /redmine
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
   Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago and kept some notes. According to what I figured out then, hiding the Redmine Mongrel behind the myhost/redmine dir is not entirely possible. True, Apache can act as a gateway by setting it up the following way:

```
ProxyPass /redmine/ http://myhost:4000/
ProxyPassReverse /redmine http://myhost:4000
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

But this would only work if the HTML returned by Redmine contained relative paths and not a single absolute path. Suppose a Redmine page /dir1/whatever.html references a CSS file /resources/styles.css. The client sees the HTML page as /redmine/dir1/whatever.html. If the CSS reference is relative, the client requests /redmine/css/styles.css, and Apache will forward it to the proxy as /css/styles.css. If the reference is absolute, though, the client asks for /css/styles.css, and Apache will not actas a proxy for that one. End of story.

NB: There is a third party module mod_proxy_html which parses the HTML and rewrites the references. But it will not be present on most servers.

The solution, it seemed, was to 301-redirect any requests within the /redmine dir explicitly to the Mongrel at http://myhost:4000 (should be possible with mod_rewrite).